# This 'switch' should be an 'if' - why?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am running my code through [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com), and I'm hitting this error:

> This `switch` should be an `if`

On this block of code:

```
switch(true)
{
    case Major === 0 && Minor === 0 && Patch < 433:
        upgraded = upgraded.replace(/(\s+)skill(\d)=/gm, '$1section_8_$2_body=');
    /* falls through */
    case Major === 0 && Minor === 0 && Patch < 442:
        upgraded = upgraded.replace(/test=/gm, 'void=');
    /* falls through */
    case Major === 0 && Minor === 0 && Patch < 459:
        upgraded = upgraded.replace(/another=/gm, 'void=');
    /* falls through */
}
```

From Googling I've found [this Github issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/198), but it looks like that was because there was only 1 `case`.

How can I fix this? I see no reason this `switch` should be an `if`. Could the fact I'm using `switch(true)` have something to do with it?

Aside: the code lints fine on the online version (I'm using the Notepad++ plugin).

Comment: I agree with JSHint. That `switch` doesn't look too good...

Comment: @elclanrs How would you rewrite it? I kind of agree... this could become a behemoth when there are lots of upgrade paths.

Comment: Well, `Patch` (why leading caps?) seems to be the only variable there. You could use `if, elseif` or find a pattern to abstract it into a dictionary lookup. Can' t tell you for sure without seeing other parts of the code.

Comment: @elclanrs `Major`, `Minor`, and `Patch` are all variables. It's version information for a file that gets loaded, to upgrade it to be compatible with the version of the software currently running.

Comment: I mean "variable" as in "the only part the varies". `Major` and `Minor` are the same, I don't understand why the fallthrough.

Comment: @elclanrs Ah, I understand you now. `Major` and `Minor` are both `0` for the moment because the software is still pre-release. When the software ships, it will be `Major: 1, Minor: 0, Patch: 0`. I'll give you an example to demonstrate why fall throughs are necessary. Suppose the software is on `v0.0.500`; the user loads a file made in  `v0.0.321`. The software first needs to upgrade the file to `v0.0.433`, then to `v0.0.442`, then finally to `v0.0.459`. If the user were to have loaded a file made in `v0.0.435`, it'd skip the first upgrade path, but do the last 2.

Comment: Then it seems like a good case for an object lookup. Add all your cases to an object and assign a function to each one that does what's necessary for the update, then when you get the current version if it's older, lookup all the updates from this version up and execute the functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like :

```
if(Major === 0 && Minor === 0){
    if(Patch < 433) {
        upgraded = upgraded.replace(/(\s+)skill(\d)=/gm, '$1section_8_$2_body=');
    }
    if(Patch < 442) {
        upgraded = upgraded.replace(/test=/gm, 'void=');
    }
    if(Patch < 459) {
        upgraded = upgraded.replace(/another=/gm, 'void=');
    }
}
```

It keeps the statements DRYer and is a little easier to read imo.  A switch would be useful if you were doing direct equality on a value but the `<` takes away all the "advantages" of a switch statement.

Comment: The difference with this and the question is that in the question if the switch evaluates true in any case, it still does the following things. In your solution it does only one.

For example if Patch is < 433, the switch will change upgraded three times, in your solution it will only change it once.

Comment: @dajavax I don't think that's the case (excuse the pun). Could you tell me your reasoning behind your thinking? If `Patch` < 433, it's also < 442 and 459, so pllee's code would change `upgraded` three times as well, no?

Comment: Switches continue doing execution of the following cases even if they are not true unless you add a break before the start of the case. Edit: nevermind, I wasn´t doing the maths.

Answer (score -1):

A `switch` statement is meant to test a single variable or expression against a finite known list of possible values (an *enumeration*)

```
var userColor = 'red';

switch(userColor){
  case 'red':
      alert('Stop');
      break;
  case 'yellow':
      alert('Slow');
      break;
  case 'green':
      alert('Go');
      break;
}
```

That code is essentially a shortcut for:

```
if(userColor == 'red'){
  alert('Stop');
}else if(userColor == 'yellow'){
  alert('Slow');
}else if(userColor == 'green'){
  alert('Go')
}
```

In the code you supplied, the only determining factor is the value of `Patch` since the rest of the variables are always 0.

I would recommend refactoring your code to a series of if/else statements

```
if(Patch < 433){
  //...
}else if(Patch < 442){
  //...
}else if(Patch < 459){
  //...
}else{
  //... fall through
}
```

Comment: The other variables *aren't* always 0. In actuality, this `switch` currently has about 50 `cases`. Besides, your bottom block of code could easily be rewritten as `switch(Patch){ case 433: ... case 442: ... case 459: ... }`

Comment: We can only help based on the supplied information. If there is more to know edit your question and provide the details

Comment: You can read the comments on the question for more information.

Comment: Also, **your code does not function correctly**, since it does not fall through.

Comment: I didn't include a fall through since there was no `default` in your switch above. I've added it now. Not sure I deserved a down vote, but whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I *do* appreciate the time you've spent trying to help! That's not a fall through though. In a series of `if/else if/else`'s, you'd simply strip the `else` from every instance of `else if` (leaving lots of plain `if`'s). This is called a "fall through" when used in a `switch`. The downvote was because your answer is incorrect, and the point of downvotes is to indicate a wrong answer. Also, my question is *why* the `switch` should be an `if`, not how to change it to an `if`.

Comment: What he means by fall through is that if it enters the first if, it won't do the instructions of the other two. The switch would because there is no "break" in each case.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I had missed the comments in the sample code. I'll take a stab at a better refactoring...